# Un uso del $timeout y $apply() que no se si es correcto en angularJs 1.xx

Tags: angularjs

Me han pasado un desarrollo angularJs 1.xx para revisar y deseaba asegurarme de si es correcto el uso que veo se hace en muchos de los controladores de esta construcción:

```
 $timeout(function(){
     $rootScope.$apply();
 });
```

Sobre todo dentro de funciones de watchers

```
$scope.$watch(function() {}
```

Que utilidad puede tener. No debería incluso bastar con :

```
$timeout(function(){

});
```

¿Una duda, puede afectar en el rendimiento del desarrollo angularJs el injectar en muchos controladores la referencia a $rootScope si no se usa en él?

Answer (score 0):

@Falinsito no andas en mal camino, el garbage collector inteligente de los navegadores aunque no le indiques que debe limpiar memoria lo hace siempre y cuando las referencias parezcan que no se van a volver a utilizar.

Esto ayuda a corregir muchos errores antiguos provocados con el tema de generacion de html asociado a variables sobre todo en Jquery.

Si se abusa de esta técnica de paso por referencia sobre todo de objetos (en este caso controladores de angularJs) será muy dificil que el garbage collector trabaje en condiciones optimas.

Si ademas todo esto ocurre dentro del ui-router de una aplicacion web grande o con unos requirimientos altos puede ser perfectamente un camino para llegar al memoryLeak , parada cardiaca del browser XD o de ti mismo si no eres capaz de arreglarlo mientras te presionan para que lo hagas.